# Rendering two table titles next to each other correctly

Tags: html, css

so I have two tables that I have displaying next to each other perfectly, but I also have two `<h3>` elements that are titles to the tables.. and I am looking for this:

```
 <h3>     <h3>
|----|   |----|
|----|   |----|
|----|   |----|
```

but instead I am getting this:

```
   |----|   |----|
   |----|   |----|
   |----|   |----|
<h3>     <h3>
```

```css
.table1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.title1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.title2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="title1">Table Title</h3>
<table class="table1">
  *** Table 1 ***
</table>

<h3 class="title2">Table 2 Title</h3>
<table class="table2">
  *** Table 2 ***
</table>
```

So, what I am doing wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Care to create a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use the `caption` tag, and `inline-table` instead `inline-block` to preserve table layout ?

```css
table {
  display: inline-table;
  background: gray;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
caption {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
caption {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <caption>table caption</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table2">
  <caption>table caption</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of bootstrap? It gives you a grid system that is perfect for this. Having said that, here is a solution for you.

```
<style>

.table_container { width: 100%; }
.left_table_container, .right_table_container {
    width: 49%;
    float:left;
}

.title1{
    display: inline-block;
}
.title2{
    display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<div class='table_container'>
    <div class='left_table_container'>
        <h3 class="title1">Table Title</h3>
        <br>
        <table class="table1">
            *** Table 1 ***
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class='right_table_container'>
        <h3 class="title2">Table 2 Title</h3>
        <br>
        <table class="table2">
            *** Table 2 ***
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a div around each column

HTML:

```
<div class="col">
  <h3 class="title1">Table Title</h3>
  <table class="table1">
    *** Table 1 ***
  </table>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <h3 class="title2">Table 2 Title</h3>
  <table class="table2">
   *** Table 2 ***
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col{
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
}
.table1{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table2{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.title1{
}
.title2{
}
```

EDIT: Fiddle added: https://jsfiddle.net/Nillervision/5qvLq2t3/

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap grid system for this purpose

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!